# How to destroy tkinter mainloop when exception occurs in any module running in daemon thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I wrote a Python (3.7) application that uses tkinter as GUI and runs the main function in a daemon thread. Is there a way to destroy the tkinter mainloop when an exception occurs in that daemon thread?

The issue is that the program has multiple modules. Is there a way to kill the mainloop if that happens in any of them? Otherwise the user will be left with a frozen GUI.

Here is the piece of code starting the thread:

```
import logging
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def main_thread():

    if check_input():  # user provided necessary input
        program_thread = threading.Thread(target=program_pipeline)  # runs main
        program_thread.daemon = True  # daemon thread can be killed anytime?
        program_thread.start()
        block_user_entries()
        clear_results()  # from a previous run

    else:
        logging.info("\n--------------- TRY AGAIN -------------------\n")
        ublock_user_entries()
```

The  `program_pipeline` communicates with multiple modules and packages

The thread starts when user clicks a button

```
analyze_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Analyze", state="normal", command=main_thread)
analyze_button.grid(column=2, row=0, pady=2, sticky=(W))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just pass root to all of your modules, and call `root.destroy()` when the exception occurs. Alternatively if you don't want to pass root to all of your modules, recursively call `widget.winfo_parent` till it returns root, and then destroy.

Comment: Looking at the code provided, exception in daemon should not leave the frozen GUI. Assuming  `block_user_entries()` or `clear_results()` functions are not waiting for daemon to complete.

Can you please provide more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am interpreting this correctly, you are looking for a way to interrupting main thread from a daemon.

Now, generally this is not a recommended option, you can do the same using low level [`_thread.interrupt_main()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/_thread.html).

If you provide more information a better solution can be thought of.

```
import _thread
import threading
import tkinter as tk


def program_pipeline():
    try:
        # DO STUFF
        # calling other modules that may raise exception/error
        raise ValueError("Error")
    except BaseException as be:
        print("Exception in daemon", be)
        _thread.interrupt_main()


def main_thread():

    program_thread = threading.Thread(target=program_pipeline)
    program_thread.daemon = True
    program_thread.start()


root = tk.Tk()
analyze_button = tk.Button(root, text="Analyze", state="normal", command=main_thread)
analyze_button.grid(column=2, row=0, pady=2, sticky=tk.W)

try:
    root.mainloop()
except KeyboardInterrupt as kie:
    print("exception in main", kie)
```

Comment: That did it for me! Thanks a lot!